# Nutch 1.4 and Solr 3.6 - Nutch not crawling 301/302 redirects

Tags: solr, nutch

I am having an issue where the initial page is crawled by the redirect is not being crawled or indexed.

I have the http.redirect.max property set to 5, I have attempted values 0, 1, and 3.

```
<property>
  <name>http.redirect.max</name>
  <value>5</value>
  <description>The maximum number of redirects the fetcher will follow when
  trying to fetch a page. If set to negative or 0, fetcher won't immediately
  follow redirected URLs, instead it will record them for later fetching.
  </description>
</property>
```

I have also attempted to clear out a majority of what is in the regex-urlfilter.txt and crawl-urlfilter.txt. Other than the website being crawled this is the only other params in these files.

```
# skip file: ftp: and mailto: urls
-^(file|ftp|mailto):

# skip image and other suffixes we can't yet parse
-\.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|sit|eps|wmf|zip|ppt|mpg|xls|gz|rpm|tgz|mov|MOV|exe|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|PDF|pdf|js|JS|swf|SWF|ashx|css|CSS|wmv|WMV)$
```

Also it seems like Nutch is crawling and pushing only pages that have querystring parameters.

When looking at the output.

```
http://example.com/build    Version: 7
Status: 4 (db_redir_temp)
Fetch time: Fri Sep 12 00:32:33 EDT 2014
Modified time: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
Retries since fetch: 0
Retry interval: 2700 seconds (0 days)
Score: 0.04620983
Signature: null
Metadata: _pst_: temp_moved(13), lastModified=0: http://example.com/build/
```

There is a default IIS redirect occuring throwing a 302 to add the trailing slash. I have made sure this slash is already added on all pages. So unsure why this is being redirected.

Just a bit more information, here are some parameters I have tried.

```
depth=5 (tried 1-10)
threads=30 (tried 1 - 30)
adddays=7 (tried 0, 7)
topN=500 (tried 500, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) on the webserver to see exactly what is being served, and on the machine Nutch is on to see what's being requested.  If they're on the same server, great.  Try that and add HTTP to your filter box after the capture.